# How to use RxBluetoothKit in Swift?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxbluetooth

I’m new to bluetooth low energy, I need to develop two applications where one act as a central and other one act as a peripheral. Central scan for particular id and peripheral advertise particular id when both id match central able to pass data to peripheral,  I need to complete that task using RxBluetoothKit but I don’t understand from where to start and I don’t understand documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Detailed manual of how to use this library is available on its GigHub wiki page:

[RxBluetoothKit Tutorial](https://github.com/Polidea/RxBluetoothKit/wiki)

It covers all simple cases. 
But for more advanced solutions RxSwift knowledge is mandatory.